# Difference between Pathfinder organized and core

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, pathfinder-society

I play Pathfinder with a group, but I've never played it a con. I'm taking my daughter to Origins this year, and we need to build characters for the Pathfinder society. What's the difference between Organized Play, and Core when it comes to building a character?

Thanks!  :  )

Answer (score 5):

The difference between a normal Organized Play character and an Organized Play Core Mode character is very simple:  **Core characters can only use certain options, most notably the Core Rulebook.**  Core characters can also use the [Character Traits Web Enhancement](http://paizo.com/download/pathfinder/CharacterTraits.zip) and the [Roleplaying Guild Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k4).  No other products (Pathfinder Player Companion, Pathfinder Campaign Setting, Pathfinder RPG - Ultimate... or Advanced... books, etc.) can be used as legal options for a Core Mode Character.

The Roleplaying Guild Guide details every thing you need to know about making Pathfinder Society characters, in standard or Core mode - it's the newest version of the book formerly known as the Guide to Organized Play, and **is** the rules for PFS.

Answer (score 3):

The Pathfinder Society provides all this information (and there's a lot of it) [in their section on the Paizo Web site](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/playerResources).  The Guide is the key document you're looking for, it lists allowed sources, disallowed options, etc. for the various game modes.

If it seems like too much information, you can always use the iconic pregen characters (available on that same page).

Comment: Sorry, @mxyzplk, it's an old answer but I must -1 it. The difference pretty much boils down to what gatherer818 states in his answer. And yours to me feels like it is a [link-only](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) leading to a global Guild Resources disambiguation page rather than at lest [this document here at page 8](http://paizo.com/products/btpy84k4).